# Checking an element is disabled using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, puppeteer

I have a button that has an initial state of `disabled` -

```
<button type = "submit" class="ant-btn ant-btn-primary ant-btn-lg" disabled>
```

The `disabled` attribute is not present once the conditions are met - so the HTML becomes

```
<button type = "submit" class="ant-btn ant-btn-primary ant-btn-lg">
```

I want to check that the button has attribute `disabled`, however since the attribute has no value in it, I am not able to find to a way to do so.

For example, if the `disabled` attribute had something like this

```
<button type = "submit" class="ant-btn ant-btn-primary ant-btn-lg" disabled = "disabled">
```

then I can do something like this

```
let button = await page.$('button');
let valueHandle = await input.getProperty('disabled');
assert.equal(await valueHandle.jsonValue(), 'disabled');
```

but since there is no value for the attribute, how to proceed in this case?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here's a comprehensive solution showing how to solve your problem using:

[`page.$()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageselector), [`page.$$()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageselector-1), [`page.$eval()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1), [`page.$$eval()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args), [`page.$x()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagexexpression), and [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args).

```
// Using page.$()
const is_disabled = await page.$('button[disabled]') !== null;

// Using page.$$()
const is_disabled = (await page.$$('button[disabled]')).length !== 0;

// Using page.$eval()
const is_disabled = await page.$eval('button[disabled]', button => button !== null).catch(error => error.toString() !== 'Error: Error: failed to find element matching selector "button[disabled]"');

// Using page.$$eval()
const is_disabled = await page.$$eval('button[disabled]', buttons => buttons.length !== 0);

// Using page.$x()
const is_disabled = (await page.$x('//button[@disabled]')).length !== 0;

// Using page.evaluate()
const is_disabled = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('button[disabled]') !== null);
```

Answer (score 15):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
const isDisabled = await page.$eval('button', (button) => {
  return button.disabled;
});
```

Your value for whether the button is disabled or not should then be stored in the `isDisabled` variable.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, you could change your [`page.$()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.6.0/docs/api.md#pageselector) query to `button[disabled]`. A `null` result implies the button is not disabled. To check for enabled buttons, query for `button:not([disabled])`.

```
const disabledButton = await page.$('button[disabled]');
const isDisabled = disabledButton !== null;

const enabledButton = await page.$('button:not([disabled])');
const isEnabled = enabledButton !== null;
```

[demo](https://puppeteersandbox.com/xXTMlscI)

Comment: @Amit I recommend posting a question so that someone familiar with the topic can help. But fyi, I don't see `page.locator()` in the API docs for puppeteer.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to check that the button has the attribute disabled, however since the attribute has no value in it, I am not able to find a way to do so.

The present attribute is what you check since [disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled) is a boolean attribute.

The answers provided so far all work. What I will suggest (though I do not know if at the time of the question this was available) is that you have the API work ***for*** you. Instead of checking for the condition yourself, you would wait for the element to become available. This can be done with either [waitForSelector](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v14.4.1/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options) or [waitForXPath](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v14.4.1/docs/api.md#pagewaitforxpathxpath-options). I will use XPath in this example.

HTML

```
<label for="account_email">Email</label>
<input type="email" autocomplete="username" autofocus="autofocus" id="account_email">
<button disabled>Continue</button>
```

JS

```
await page.goto('www.example.com', { waitUntil }) // go to page
await page.$x('//label[text() = "Email"]/following-sibling::input') // get input
  .then(([input]) => input.type('example@myemail.com')) // fulfill condition(valid email)
await page.waitForXPath('//button[text() = "Continue"][not(@disabled)]') // wait for button
  .then(button => button.click()) // click the button only after it is enabled
```